# How to ensure a record is always in the returned list and ordered correctly

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to write a select statement that will always include a specific record (42 in the example below) regardless of how the data is ordered.  Using `ORDER BY IIF( ID = 42, 0, 1 )` will allow the record to always show in the returned dataset but it's always at the top instead of correctly sorted.

```
ID  ID  vs  ID  ID
------      ------
42  42      0   40
0   40      1   41
1   41      2   42
2   43      3   43
3   44      4   44
4   45      5   45
5   46      6   46
6   47      7   47
7   48      8   48
8   49      42  49
```

Here is a sample I've created to illustrate various real world usage samples:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Table TABLE ( ID int );
DECLARE @ID int = 0;

WHILE ( @ID < 100 )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Table ( ID )
    VALUES ( @ID );

    SET @ID += 1;
END

SELECT TOP(10) ID 
FROM @Table
ORDER BY IIF( ID = 42, 0, 1 ), ID;

SELECT TOP(10) ID 
FROM @Table
WHERE ID > 30
ORDER BY IIF( ID = 42, 0, 1 ), ID;

SELECT TOP(10) ID 
FROM @Table
WHERE ID > 40
ORDER BY IIF( ID = 42, 0, 1 ), ID;

SELECT TOP(10) ID 
FROM @Table
WHERE ID > 50
OR ID = 42
ORDER BY IIF( ID = 42, 0, 1 ), ID;
```

I need to define the `SELECT` statement to cater for at least the above 4 variations.  All the things I tried started to get quite complex and I'm trying to keep it as clean an simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `union`?

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP(10) ID 
    FROM @Table
    ORDER BY ID

    UNION 

    SELECT ID
    FROM @Table
    WHERE ID = 42
) As x
ORDER BY ID
;
```

Comment: The sad part is that's exactly what I also came up with and it just felt like it was way overkill.  Was really hoping I missed something simpler.